# How to set terminal in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ide, qt-creator

I have a plain C++ project automatically created by the Qt Creator wizard(just the "Hello World!" one). When I press F5 to debug, there's an error in the terminal:

> Cannot connect creator comm socket /tmp/qt_temp.HP2094/stub-socket: No
>   such file or directory

I have searched for solutions in the Internet and tried this one:

> change the terminal value from x-terminal-emulator -e to
>   /usr/bin/xterm -e

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. A message box pops up saying "ptrace: Operation not permitted".

How to make my Qt Creator console application function normally?
PS: My Qt creator version is the default one in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu did some kernel hardening techniques a while back that had the wonderful effect of making `gdb`, `ptrace` and `strace` stop working without sudo permissions, as a malware prevention change. If you follow [this comment](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535) it'll allow it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution of "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope" works for me! But does that mean I use Qt Creator at the cost of making my system more vulnerable? What would you suggest if I set ptrace_scope to 0 in /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf pemanently? @Nicholas Smith

Comment: Keep in mind this has been a relatively recent security change and we've all lived happily on Linux for a long while, it was proactive not reactive. The likelihood is you'll be fine, just don't install anything you don't trust which most SO users know anyway.

Comment: OK, I'll follow your advise. Thanks again. But it's really weird Qt Creator installed via synaptic has to refer to xterm instead of the original default terminal. Why doesn't synaptic/software-center make softwares completely ready for use for the specific system? @Nicholas Smith