# No output showing up in output window

Tags: debian, qt-creator

I recently installed Qt Creator 2.5 on my Debian box and created a simple console project to test it. The program it generated was modified to become:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char junk;
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "Hello there\n";
    std::cin >>junk;

    return 0;//a.exec();
}
```

(all the things commented out are simply what the creator gave me, I've removed them to simplify it as much as possible).

Now, when I run the built executable from the command line, it works fine, outputting the `hello` message and then waiting for me to enter a character, after which it exits.

However, within Qt Creator itself, running with <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> or debugging with <kbd>F5</kbd> results in a blank window appearing and the only thing I can do is <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> to break out of it:

[image]

(ignore that breakpoint on line 8, removing it has no effect on the behaviour).

The project file is as follows:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = xyzzy
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

What could be causing this behaviour?

My understanding was that the `I` in `IDE` stood for "integrated" so I don't *really* want to have to go and debug my code with `gdb` on the command line :-)

I'm pretty certain it's not a flushing issue since, if I actually *enter* a character, nothing happens.

If I haven't provided enough info for the Qt Creator gurus out there, please let me know and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: And what happens when those lines aren't commented out?

Comment: @Chief, exactly the same. That was why I tried to simplify it, thinking that there was some magic Qt stuff going on that I wasn't aware of. Having said that, I put it back the way it was and tried running from outside Qt Creator. It just sits there in the `a.exec()`, I know that because changing that to `return 0` results in clean exit.

Comment: I used to have a similar problem on Ubuntu. This question and its answer ([How to set terminal in Qt Creator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15539547/26449)) helped me. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: @Bill, you should make that an answer so I can accept it, the actual changing of the terminal as per that linked **question** worked for me. Normally, I'd upvote the answer you pointed me to but that's actually not an issue for me. That question was _after_ they'd changed the terminal and they still had a gdb problem. Since I'm running snow-pure Debian rather than that grotesque Ubuntu monstrosity, that's not an issue for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the terminal value from **x-terminal-emulator -e** to **xterm -e** in **Tools** / **Options...** / **Environment** / **General** / **Terminal:**.